# Does IntelliJ IDEA work on a 64-bit Windows system?

Tags: java, windows, installation, ide

I have downloaded and installed IDEA 13.1. However, even having a 64-bit system, Windows has automatically installed the program in the folder `Program Files (x86)`, which is dedicated for 32-bit programs.

Is there another download for the 64-bit version or maybe a special setting to make it suitable for a 64-bit system?

Comment: You can run 32-bit programs on any regular 64-bit Windows installation.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\${Intellij Idea version}\bin`, there is an executable called `idea64.exe`. This is for 64-bit systems. You can simply change your IntelliJ shortcut path to it.

You also need to add a new environment variable `IDEA_JDK_64` pointing to your 64-bit JDK so IntelliJ can use a 64-bit JDK.

**idea64.exe uses this JDK search sequence:**

1. `IDEA_JDK_64` environment variable
2. `..\jre64` directory
3. system Registry
4. `JDK_HOME` environment variable
5. `JAVA_HOME` environment variable

More can be found in a related [IntelliJ support article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under).

Comment: Link sends me to a login page. It appears you need a JetBrains account to be able to "find more". Not pleasant...

Comment: This [link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under) works.

Answer (score 1):

If installing latest version as of today 2016.3.2, while installing the installation wizard prompts to either choose 32-bit or 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Java SDK 64bit so it shows the options to install IntelliJ 64bit.