# Intellij idea 32 bit vs 64 bit speed and performance

Tags: intellij-idea

Currently I am using intellij idea 14.0.3(earlier I was using 12.1.4) on 64 bit windows 8.1.

When we install it, the installer creates the shortcut in start menu and other places which defaults to the 32 bit .exe file even on a 64 bit system.

I know that I can use the 64 bit executable to run idea in 64 bit mode as given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22514093/1291122) SO answer.

But is there any significant performance difference between the two versions of the IDE?

And which executable is recommended for 64 bit systems? Shall I keep using 32 bit? or shall I switch to 64bit version?

Comment: In this day and age, there is *little* to be gained from running a 32-bit application on an 64-bit operating system.

Comment: @Makoto then why does intellij idea defaults to 32 bit executable even on 64 bit systems? Doesn't jetbrains know this?

Comment: It...doesn't?  I've only ever used IntelliJ IDEA on 64-bit OS X and Linux, so I've never run into this problem.  Do you, perchance, have a 32-bit version of Java?

Comment: @Makoto I am sure I don't have a 32 bit java. I have 64 bit jdk and jre

Comment: @Makoto finally its been answered. Check Ivaylo D. Ivanov's reply.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The difference between running the 32 and 64 bits launcher is which Java will be used to start the IDE and what are the vmoptions parameters passed to it.

When starting the 32 bit one, IDEA uses it's own bundled 32 bit JRE. If there is no such one, IDEA tries to find 32 bit JRE in several places on specific order (%IDEA_HOME%, %JDK_HOME%, %JAVA_HOME%). The values in idea.exe.vmoptions are passed to it.

When starting the 64 bit one, it tries to find 64 bit JRE in several places on specific order. The values in idea64.exe.vmoptions are passed to it.

So if you want to allocate 2 GB RAM or more (with -xmx), this is not going to happen with 32 bit Java (resp. IDEA). And for large projects using less than 2GB  causes the IDE to hang a lot. For smaller projects I don't think you'll feel any difference.

For reference this is the bug about this, so far they are not acting on it:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146040

Comment: Well that bug I definitely suspected. And apart from that what comes as a blessing in disguise is that it has given me more insight on why my intellij idea freezes so much when I am working on a heavy project!! Looks like you are a member of intellij team eh?

Comment: Hi @rahulserver, no I am not - just also working on a heavy project and pushing Intellij team from time to time to fix some annoying issues :)

Comment: I had issues with IDEA crashing (just exiting suddenly for no reason) when opening five or six projects concurrently. I switched to the 64-bit launcher and added `-Xmx2048m` to the vmoptions file and the issue seems to have gone. So perhaps it's not just heavy projects but multiple projects that 64-bit can help with. IDEA version 2016.1.

Comment: Is this difference applicable only in Windows?

Comment: Yes, these launchers are for Windows. If you use the .bat file to launch IDEA (.sh for Linux, don't know for OSX), there is a logic which basically tries to guess is there 64 bit java and if so, uses it.