# IntelliJ IDEA won't start on AMD Athlon XP 1500+ (Windows 7)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have installed Windows 7 to test IntelliJ IDEA, and when I run it, the splash screen progress bar goes to 100%, shows up the initial window, and crashes.

My JDK version is 8u202. Strangely, I tested it in the past with Xubuntu, and it starts flawlessly without crashes, with OpenJDK 8u191.

I looked at [error log](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/_persistent/java_error_in_idea_3988.log?file=74-636904&c=false&updated=1552832041851) and [idea.log](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/_persistent/idea.log?file=74-636903&c=false&updated=1552832026190) files, and the error log says EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION, however idea.log reveals nothing.

I have made a [bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-209119) and asked a [support question](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003287099-IntelliJ-IDEA-32-bit-won-t-start-on-AMD-Athlon-XP-1500-Windows-7-), but neither got a response.

Comment: is your system OS 32 bit or 64 bit?, can you open terminal any execute command $java, and $echo $JAVA_HOME, what output you are getting.

Comment: hopefully this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33010846/2987755

Comment: Your question was submitted on Sunday. Please allow the support team at least 8 business hours to respond. At the first look it appears to be an issue with the native library on 32-bit Windows and you can try disabling it by adding `-Didea.use.native.fs.for.win=false` in the `.vmoptions` file. Please see my response in YouTrack for more details.

Comment: @dkb Eofla is using the correct JDK version for the 32-bit Windows system, the issue is a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA is using a native library `IdeaWin32.dll` for some file system operations on Windows. This library is compiled with the default options using Visual Studio C compiler (`cl.exe`), therefore it may use **SSE2** instructions which are not available on your CPU.

Workarounds (choose one):

- Replace `IdeaWin32.dll` library in `IDEA_HOME\bin` with a version compiled without SSE2 instructions (with `/arch:SSE` [option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/arch-x86?view=vs-2017) instead of `/arch:SSE2`) ([attached to YouTrack ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-209119#focus=streamItem-27-3336832.0-0)).
- Disable the native file system library for Windows by adding `-Didea.use.native.fs.for.win=false` in the [idea.vmoptions](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544869) file

Unrelated to the original problem, but I'd recommend running IntelliJ IDEA under JetBrains Runtime instead of the Oracle JDK. Windows installer has an option to download and use the 32-bit version of JetBrains Runtime automatically or you can [download and switch to it manually](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879).

Comment: Thank you! I will try to replace the original SSE2 IdeaWin32.dll with non-SSE2 IdeaWin32.dll tomorrow because of my electricity.

Comment: Thank you! The non-SSE2 IdeaWin32.dll made IntelliJ IDEA no longer crash!