# git fails from IntelliJ on Windows 10 with fork: can't reserve memory for parent stack

Tags: git, intellij-idea, windows-10

I'm not sure what the cause for this problem, but git fails since I upgraded to Windows 10, from IntelliJ only.

Whenever I use it from SmartGit or Cygwin CLI, everything works as it should, but running `pull`, `rebase` or anything else from withing IntelliJ always ends up with:

```
C:\cygwin64\home\nati\git\afa\devel\java>git pull
      1 [main] git 9112 C:\cygwin64\bin\git.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - fork: can't reserve memory for parent stack 0x600000 - 0x800000, (child has 0x400000 - 0x600000), Win32 error 487
    528 [main] git 9112 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to git.exe.stackdump
      9 [main] git 15628 fork: child -1 - forked process 9112 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
error: cannot fork() for git-pull: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I tried restarting or some other things I found online, but no good.
I'm not even sure whether its a Win10, Git, or Idea issue.

Comment: Try git shell instead -- it's a lot easier than cygwin

Comment: Easier in what sense?  I'm using intelliJ gui

Comment: Easier in that it works without this type of fault. The error is in cygwin, not git -- you can't currently fork a 64bit process from a 32bit client. Git shell doesn't have this problem, and fewer problems == easier.

Comment: It does sound worth a try. Could you please provide a link?

Comment: It's part of the git for windows package: https://git-for-windows.github.io/

Comment: Thanks ! The problem really was forking a 64 bit process from a 32 bit one. currently I'll use the [idea.64.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22514023/does-intellij-idea-work-on-a-64-bit-system) (it works...) but soon enough i'll give git-shell a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Engineer Dollery mentioned in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249511/git-fails-from-intellij-on-windows-10-with-fork-cant-reserve-memory-for-parent?noredirect=1#comment60130452_36249511) the problem is I tried to fork a 64 bit operation (cygwin) from a 32 bit application (IntelliJ).

The solution is to use the 64-bit IntelliJ (idea64.exe)